# Queue size as param

Tags: apache-nifi

how can I get queue size as parameter?
[image]

Comment: what is your use case ? - do you want to report the queue size at a point in time ?

Comment: What the purpose of it? Maybe there is another way to solve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Directly, I think you can't, number of flowfile in queue is dynamic.

One way to do this is to use counter.

- set a counter to 0
- connect a update counter +1 processor between you executeSQL and logAttribute (use these processor in process group)
- set group level flow file concurrency to be sure only 1 flowfile going to LogAttribute
- your number in queue will be counter - 1
- after you LogAttribute processor update counter to counter - 1

you will probably need 3 differents counters and 3 logAttribut processors , 1 for each queue